# How do I concatenate two videos and apply a logo using moviepy in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, moviepy, video-conversion

```py
import os

import moviepy
import moviepy.editor as mp
from moviepy.video.compositing.concatenate import concatenate_videoclips

list1 = os.listdir("D:\\facemask")
a = len(list1)

for lst in range(a):
    video_path = "D:\\facemask\\" + list1[lst]
    video = mp.VideoFileClip(video_path)
    outer = mp.VideoFileClip("D:\\peter.mp4")
    logo = mp.ImageClip("D:\\twinkle_logo.png")\
        .set_duration(video.duration)\
        .resize(height=50)\
        .margin(right=8, top=8, opacity=0)\
        .set_pos(("right", "top"))
    concat = concatenate_videoclips(video, outer)
    final = mp.CompositeVideoClip([concat, logo])
    path = "D:\\facemask\\out\\" + list1[lst] + ".mp4"
    final.write_videofile(path)

print("Operation done")
```

Comment: You want to do this all within main memory?

Comment: I'd use ffmpeg for this.

Comment: @GunnerStone yes